# Javascript iterator won't work but hardcoded number will

Tags: javascript, loops, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create dynamic markers using google maps api and am having problems when using a variable tat is iterated over.

I've ommited the code for generating the markers and the map because it seems to work fine. This is the code for generating the info window.

This code produces the error of 'this_marker_info[$n]' [undefined] is not an object

```
for(var $n = 0; $n < business.length; $n++){
   google.maps.event.addListener(this_marker[$n], 'click', function() {
       this_marker_info[$n].open(map, this_marker[$n]);
   });      
}
```

This code works

```
for(var $n = 0; $n < business.length; $n++){
   google.maps.event.addListener(this_marker[$n], 'click', function() {
       this_marker_info[0].open(map, this_marker[0]);
   });      
}
```

All I did was swap $n with the number 0 in the second example in the line tat reads "this_marker_info[$n].open(map, this_marker[$n]);"

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It could be that the `this_marker_info` array is sparse (= that it has "holes")...

Comment: ... wait a minute. You are iterating over `business`, but then trying to access elements of `this_marker` and `this_marker_info`. How do you know that those arrays are as long as the `business` array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical closure problem.
By the time  `this_marker_info[$n].open(map, this_marker[$n]);` gets executed you've finished the loop and the value of `$n` is `business.length`.

The solution is to write a closure:

```
for(var $n = 0; $n < business.length; $n++){
    (function ($the_actual_n) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(this_marker[$the_actual_n], 'click', function() {
            this_marker_info[$the_actual_n].open(map, this_marker[$the_actual_n]);
        });
    }($n)); // <-- call this 'anonymous' function with $n
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `Array.forEach()` is a nice tidy way to fix it:

```
business.forEach(function(item, $n) {
   google.maps.event.addListener(this_marker[$n], 'click', function() {
       this_marker_info[$n].open(map, this_marker[$n]);
   });      
}
```

This way, the containing function never increments `$n`, so it will reliably keep it's original value.

To use `Array.forEach()` in older browsers, [see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility).

Comment: forEach does indeed circumvent this problem because underwater it's doing the closure for you. This is typically the way to go, either use forEach or your own array-map function.